# What steps can be taken to ensure the security of a PHP application?

Tags: php, security

While filling out secure forms on bank websites, I have always wondered how they know their application is completely secure. Sure you know you are on SSL, your account "should" be secure, and hopefully the security question, account throttle, timeouts etc. should keep your account safe. But what is the best way to test this? And what determines how "safe" your application is? What if there was a bug in your code somewhere, then it would not matter how many safeguards you have in place.

I recently created a login for a website which will log the user out automatically after 15 mins, will lock their account after 3 failed attempts, contains a security question, and runs on SSL. But I need to know what determines the security of a program.

Thanks for any help!
Metropolis

**EDIT**

The main question is. "What is the best way to test for PHP security". Is there steps to take to ensure this. Surely there must be.

Comment: `I have always wondered how they know their application is completely secure.` They don't know that - they just say they do ;)

Comment: This question is really, really broad - probably too broad. PHP application security, and web application security in general is a huge field and a science in itself. There are some basic check lists for PHP apps, see the following duplicates:

Comment: [What security issues should I look out for in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165040/what-security-issues-should-i-look-out-for-in-php)

Comment: [PHP Security best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices)

Comment: [Common unknown PHP security pitfalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918113/common-unknown-php-security-pitfalls)

Comment: Is there such a thing as a 100% secure application? I doubt that...

Comment: You would think banks get audited on things like this right? I sometimes see claims on other programs that they have "bank level security" as if that is some type of a standard.

Comment: +1 for being concerned about security, even if the question cannot be reasonably answered.

Comment: The question is, what is the best way to test for security?

Comment: @Metropolis what the variety of responses should show you is that there is no simple best way to test for security. Take some time to read through the links provided to get an overview.

Comment: @Pekka you wrote 6 of the comments above, and then you say something like "what the variety of responses should show you". And this question is not a duplicate of another question. I always check before I ask, and nobody has ever shown a step by step way of testing security. And you posting a bunch of links is not helping either. I have already seen all of those.

Comment: @Metropolis a step by step way of testing security is an illusionary requirement. *Understanding* security and having it ingrained in every programming step is the only way to go. When you have that, you can work productively with a check list like the one you accepted (which by the way looks good and I didn't know about.) without the understanding, any check list is pointless. But suit yourself; and I will simply not bother you with input in the future.

Comment: @pekka I agree with you about "Understanding security and having it ingrained in every programming step is the only way to go" and I feel like I already do this. But even though I feel confident in my security abilities, I also know that the worst thing is a programmer who "thinks" they know security. I do appreciate your input though and I am sorry if I was rude. I just hate asking a question and getting a bunch of links. It always feels like the person did not try very hard.

Comment: @Metropolis all right. It's just that most people who want a step-by-step list usually don't know enough about the issue, and offering a few in-depth links (which I always check for quality before posting) is the best that can be done. That was obviously not the case in your case. But it's just *comments* - posting links like that is a service for which the commenter gains nothing. Anyway, the answer you accepted looks good and is really interesting to me, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a standard for security verification of web applications: [OWASP ASVS](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-asvs/wiki/ASVS).

It prescribes a checklist of all the processes you must have in place, and all the facts you must have verified before you can claim a certain level of security. I suggest you go read the detailed requirements to know what is involved. An example of an ASVS requirement is "Verify that a positive validation pattern is defined and applied to all input."

The requirements are grouped into 4 levels:

- Level 1 is appropriate for small low-risk apps
- Level 2 is appropriate for typical business apps
- Level 3 is appropriate for high-reliability apps
- Level 4 is appropriate for life-critical apps

Another possible standard to adhere to is the [Microsoft Security Development Lifecycle (SDL)](http://www.microsoft.com/security/sdl/default.aspx). It's the process they use for their own products. The SDL is more process-oriented, and more generic.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to be 100% sure, believe it or not, banks *are* actually broken into from time to time, recently here in Denmark a serious vulnerability has been found in the goverment backed "NemID" (Easy ID) where it doesn't log you out even though it tells you it has.

However, to try and nip stuff like that in the butt, try and break it yourself, think like a hacker, its your code, what little quirks and workarounds are there that could possibly let you in.

http://labs.securitycompass.com/index.php/exploit-me/ has a bunch of resources for checking for XSS, sqlinjection etc, also I highly recommend [The Web Application Hackers Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470170778)

Also, if you are very serious about your security, get an external reputed consultant/company to review your code.

...But before all that, please consider this, is what you are protecting important enough to pull out the nukes... or is a breadknife enough?

Answer (score 1):

> But I need to know what determines the
>   security of a program.

This is a very hard question to give a general answer to. It sounds like you have done everything in your power to secure your application. If security is *that* important to you it may be an idea to hire a company specialized in security audits.

Answer (score 0):

You are only talking about the front-end / user-visible security. That´s just one aspect, don´t forget about the back-end security; the server, the database, the php-code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not exactly answering your question, let me just give you some food for thought regarding the "lock their account after 3 failed attempts" practice, which can be easily abused and is a form of denial of service.

Even though this is not a *security* issue per se but more of a usability issue arising from securing a system, it should be a consideration when thinking about security, and is on my mind these days because I've come across some pretty silly implementations of it recently, especially in e-banking applications:

- 2 of my banks will lock you out after 3 failed login attempts. You'll notice I don't have a "within X time" constraint, because there isn't any. If you mistype your password today, and you did so a month ago and again 8 months ago, it will lock you out. It does not reset once you log in successfully.
- Couple this with a policy of forcing you to change your password atleast once a month and requiring strictly 6-digit numeric passwords and you have alot of users being blocked all the time. Atleast they will unblock it after verifying your identity over the phone so you can retry if you believe you know your password.
- Another one will lock you out after 4 failed login attempts. I'm not sure about a time constraint there because it only happened once to me so far. However, they cannot unlock your account after phone verification, nor in person at the bank itself. The policy is to send you a new password, by mail. *Mail*, not e-mail. I've been waiting for mine for over a week now.
- In my case all these happened to me following my actions, but someone could easily annoy me by locking me out if he knows my username, or the general public just by trying random ones.

My point is that automatic lockout is pretty widespread, but it takes effort to make it a deterrent to attackers while keeping it user-friendly to the legitimate users. Perhaps:

- After 3 failed attempts ask if the user has forgotten his password and offer the support phone number
- If the failed attempts are too frequent or there's any robotic behaviour (bad UA, instant submit after loading the page), show a captcha along the login form.
- As the failed attempts continue, increase the time to wait before being allowed a new attempt. For example after 3 failed attempts, require the user to wait 30 seconds before retrying. Another 2 failed, wait 2 minutes.
- If you are going to lock the account, offer again the phone support number in the same page so a frustrated user will be able to get some help.

Any other ideas?